# Make creating a dev story part of the "new user" privilege

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, developer-story, spam

Users with developer stories (beyond *very* minimal stories) currently can't be destroyed by moderators. Spammers [are using this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7785160/goa-escorts-services) (warning, spammer link) to circumvent destruction of their user accounts, which is less than ideal. Obviously SE staff can still remove these user accounts, but the extra time and effort involved in getting destructions processed is wasting moderator time.

Developer stories are also the perfect target for spammers because they are a freeform page that can contain URLs, with no way to spam-flag individual developer stories.

I propose that creating a developer story should be part of the [new user privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user), which is the threshold at which posting images or more than 2 links (which are also counter-spam measures) is enabled. This would likely prevent 99% of spammers from ever creating a developer story, and would mean moderators can destroy spammers again.

Comment: I believe that the right feature-request to ask here would be to allow moderators to destroy user accounts even if they have dev stories. If those users deserve to be destroyed, then they don't deserve to get a job.

Comment: @Zanon Creeping normality could mean that that leads the way that Google might if their motto wasn't "Don't be evil". The "they don't deserve to get a job" part is the issue there.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I can't deny, this is *pretty annoying*. I've been out sick for a while, so right now this is what the deletion queue looks like:

[image: a list of about 18 users pending deletion, most of them because of dev story]

I'll bet you a dollar there isn't a single user in that list that I'm not going to approve. Heck, I've only rejected 1 deletion in the entire time dev story has existed (I'm sure other employees have rejected more than that, but still - very very low false-positive rate).

*That said...* There aren't that many of these right now. That's almost a week's worth of queued-up deletions in that screenshot; it's just not that much of a burden right now. In comparison to the thousands of dev stories being created, this isn't worth making major changes to privileges to fix.

### Visibility is the real issue here

The *immediate* problem is that there's a delay between the deletion and the dev story being hidden. Even if I'm not logged in, that escort service dev story you linked to is still perfectly visible, image and all; heck, if you signed up for an employer account you could even search for it (but... Guessing that's not the direction we should be headed for future revenue).

Fortunately, Roberta implemented a reasonable fix for this last week: when a moderator tries to delete a user with a dev story, they're immediately suspended - thus preventing them from posting more spam *and* blocking access to the dev story. There was an oversight there, in that it wasn't kicking in on spam destruction... But that's fixed now.

Long-term, we need better heuristics here. For example, if you've made no posts on the site (or better yet, all of the posts you *have* made have been deleted as spam), there's precious little reason to block deletion. Similarly, if the account is just a few days old, hasn't linked to anything on SO or a sane off-site code-focused service, it's probably not a valid story to begin with and we shouldn't be blocking deletion. She's out at the moment, but bluefeet will be doing some research here when she gets back.

Comment: Is there any reason not to simply trust the moderator's decision here? If they decide it's a spammer, just delete the dev story outright. Maybe just warn the mod that there is a dev story that is going to be deleted, and add a restriction similar to destroying users.

Comment: The short answer there @Mad is that this is what happens when you mash together two very different systems. Beyond that... I think there was some concern up-front that someone might put a lot of time into filling out a story, go around applying for jobs, and then get their account deleted and lose all that work. I've seen no evidence that this has ever happened, but that's the concern. A much better set of heuristics here would actually look for some indication that the author has put serious time into their profile *and* others have expressed interest in some way, but... we're not there yet.

Comment: @Shog9 If they've annoyed a moderator enough to get their account deleted (spamming, abuse, any number of things), do they *deserve* to still be allowed to use the dev story feature?

Comment: Well, you could apply that logic to anything, @art. We have restrictions on reputation and votes that'll throw users into the queue too, because it turns out *moderator annoyance* isn't a perfect metric here either (and having to pull backups for a well-established user because a moderator got *annoyed* ain't fun). Normally, it takes me a few seconds to sanity-check these once a day and they're gone.

Comment: "when a moderator tries to delete a user with a dev story, they're immediately suspended" - except that the last few spammers I've tried to **destroy** this hasn't happened.

Comment: _"when a moderator tries to delete a user with a dev story, they're immediately suspended"_ Sounds a bit harsh to the mod ;)

Comment: That's the oversight I mentioned above, @ChrisF - should be working now?

Comment: @Shog9 oops, missed that. Sorry. I'll let you know next time I destroy a spammer.