# Are users created only to post spam or outright nonsense destroyed or suspended?

Tags: discussion, support, spam, account-suspension

I was surprised to run across this suspension message today:

> This account is temporarily suspended
>
> This user was created to post spam or nonsense and has no other positive participation. The suspension period ends in 7 days.

I was under the impression that users created solely to post spam are destroyed rather than suspended.

Is this an automatic process or did a moderator issue this?

If a moderator did issue this, what caused the user to merely be suspended for 7 days rather than destroyed?

Comment: Much as we'd like to destroy users who spam, etc, it would probably be illegal.  User accounts ... are a different matter though.  :-)

Comment: "destroyed"... by drone XD

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329251/we-should-be-more-watchful-of-0-activity-spam-users). Unfortunately, they also spam creating accounts without making any posts using the profile as their spam content. These haven't been destroyed as of yet.

Answer (score 52):

Users created only to post spam are usually destroyed. But some crafty spammers create a dev story. When they create a dev story, they cannot be destroyed by moderators. Only CMs can destroy them. In those cases, there's is an [automatic suspension for 7 days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346169/4099593).

There's another "suspended for profile rule violations". That's for socks who have dev stories. (Fun fact, in many cases,  masters don't have a dev story, but their socks have)

Comment: Ahh so that user is in the process of being destroyed it's just that you have to wait for a CM to do it.

Comment: Yes, they get auto suspended once we initiate the destroy process, once a CM verifies they'll be sent home.

Comment: what is CM?....

Comment: @MehulMohan Community Managers https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do

Comment: what is a sock?

Comment: and this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338288/5292302?, can you give more info when possibile and not possibile?

Comment: @zok: Sock puppet, another sort of fake account.

Comment: @Petter It's all hazy to me as well. I once destroyed a account that had a 3 items in it's dev story. However one other time, the user didn't even have a dev story attached to the profile, but I couldn't destroy it. The system tells us that "The user cannot be destroyed due to an indexable dev story" when we proceed to destroy the user. (Earlier we had to suspend them manually, now the process is automated)

Comment: @PetterFriberg - They're also continually changing the thresholds on this based on our feedback. The locking of the account is a good short-term feature that was recently added. It prevents the account from doing whatever was causing a problem, while still giving SE employees time to review why we couldn't delete it and maybe see if we made a mistake.

Comment: Based on the fun fact and the on-going machine learning I expect in the next 6 to 8 weeks all accounts with a dev story to be nuked ...

Comment: @rene Nuked even if they haven't spammed? :-)

Comment: What is a spam?

Comment: @Braiam, is *irrelevant or inappropriate messages sent on the Internet to a large number of recipients*.

Comment: what a tangled web we weave

Comment: @Braiam: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spamming

Comment: @Braiam https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_(food)